# Meaning of だけは in the sense of "to do all that one can"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I have several sentences where だけは is translated as "to do all that one can".

> 覚える**だけは**覚えたのだから、後は試験の日を待つだけだ。
>   I’ve remembered everything I could, so
>   now all I have to do is wait for the day of the test to come.
>
> 指示のとおりにやる**だけは**やったが、いい結果が出るかどうか自信がない。
>    I followed the instruction and did
>   all that I could, but I have no confidence that I’ll have good
>   results.
>
> 恋愛のことは両親にも話す**だけは**話しました。
>   I told my parents everything about my love life.

Is it a special pattern or is it explicable with the "usual" meaning of だけ?
Can it be decomposed so that I can understand where だけは translated as "to do all that one can" comes from ?

Thanks

Comment: Related?? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72454/9831

Comment: Well done Chocolate, I did try to find on the forum but could not find it. Yes, they are definitely related. Maybe a fusion of the questions, or mark as duplicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a special pattern or is it explicable with the "usual" meaning of だけ?

It's [meaning (2) in this definition](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91). In this case, dake corresponds to an upper limit or the maximum possible. In English "only" usually implies a limitation or a lack but in Japanese "dake" can also imply exactitude, something like "precisely", or up to some limit or another.

> 覚えるだけは覚えたのだから、後は試験の日を待つだけだ。
>
> I’ve *remembered* everything I could, so now all I have to do is wait for the day of the test to come.

Not a good translation of 覚える, "remembered" should be "learned" or "memorised". Anyway here it means "I've learned to the limit of my capacity".

> 指示のとおりにやるだけはやったが、いい結果が出るかどうか自信がない。
>
> I followed the instruction and *did all that I could*, but I have no confidence that I’ll have good results.

Yes, here again it is the upper limit.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the detailled explaination, I have just one more question: for the upper limit meaning, is the double repetition "覚えるだけは覚えた" , "やるだけはやった" always needed ?